# Could not retrieve data from realm object

Tags: react-native, realm

I want to know about fetching data from a realm object consist of schema data

db.js-Page where realm database defined

```
  ..........................................

  export const tableProjectSchema = {

   name: TABLE_PROJECT,

   primaryKey: 'id',

   indexed:'true',

   properties: {

        id: 'int',

        project_id: 'int',

        project_name: 'string'
    }

};

 ...................................................

 export const  getProject = newProject => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>

 {  

 Realm.open(databaseOptions).then(realm => {

 realm.readOnly(() => {

 let allProjects = realm.objects(TABLE_PROJECT);

 resolve(allProjects);

});

}).catch(

  (error) => reject(error));

});
```

sample.js - Here imported db.js and calling function getProject() from this page.

```
render() {

    let Projects=Database.getProject();

    console.log("table object"+Projects);
    ...................
    }
```

I want to fetch project_name from the object 'Projects' in sample.js.

log out:
  table object[object Object]

Comment: try console.log("table object", Projects)

Comment: @Kranthi Kumar Julakanti That is what i get when JSON.stringify that object.but,that couldn't meet my need.

Comment: I want to display project_name s from that object.

Comment: If the Projects is array do it like this
for(i=0, i<Projects.length, i++) {
  name = Projects[i].project_name;
}
or loop through the object keys if Projects is a object

Comment: @KranthiKumarJulakanti I've tried it but couldn't get result.btw,i got the solution which i posted as answer.Thanks for your efforts,I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified getProject() method.

```
export const  getProject = newProject => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>

 {  

     Realm.open(databaseOptions).then(realm => {

     let allProjects = realm.objects(TABLE_PROJECT);

     resolve(allProjects);

    }).catch(

    (error) => reject(error));

  });
```

Fetched data from object using

```
 Database.getProject().then((projects) => 
 console.log(projects.forEach(project => console.log(`Project name: 
 ${project.project_name}`)))).catch((error) => { console.log(`Error in 
 fetching projects: ${error}`) });
```